# get height of a div and set the height of another div using it

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, neither have a height set in css, as I want to take whatever height they end up as and set the other div to be that height.

The javascript I have is this

```
function fixHeight() {
    var divh = document.getElementById('prCol1').height;
    document.getElementById('prCol1').innerHTML = '<ul><li>' + divh + '</li></ul>';
    document.getElementById('prCol2').style.height = divh + 'px';
}
```

I have the following line of code just to see if I am getting some kind of actual response.

```
document.getElementById('prCol1').innerHTML = '<ul><li>' + divh + '</li></ul>';
```

I have a onload set to run the function

my two divs look like this

```
<div id="prCol1">
     ..content..
</div>
<div id="prCol2" class="slideshow">
    ..content..
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `offsetHeight` - http://jsfiddle.net/HwATE/

```
function fixHeight() {
    var divh = document.getElementById('prCol1').offsetHeight; /* change this */
    document.getElementById('prCol1').innerHTML = '<ul><li>' + divh + '</li></ul>';
    document.getElementById('prCol2').style.height = divh + 'px';
}
```

Comment: I don't believe offsetHeight is fully supported by all browsers. I haven't done indepth research on if jQuery fixes the issues but that's the point of it right?

http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/

Comment: @JohnCulviner Yes, it might cause a `1px` difference, but in the OP's case it's not really relevant, I think. His goal is to make the 2 `<div>`-s equally high and exactly that will happen. I believe that's the possibility(it might even not happen) of `1px` difference in IE9 is a good trade-off for not including a 40K library(if it's not already included). And raw JS is always faster.. And `offsetHeight` is supported in every browser - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to get the height and set it.

```
var h = $("#prCol1").height();
$("#prCol2").height(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get height by this code:

```
document.getElementById('YourElementID').clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are jQuery plugins to do this in a general way.  [Here's one](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery here. You can't get the height of an element like you are trying in any browser I know of. Here is the code if you use jQuery which is very straightforward. I wouldn't try to do this without jQuery because browsers can be different in respect to how you access height.

```
function fixHeight() {
    var $prCol1 = $('#prCol1');
    var divh = $prCol1.height();
    $prCol1.html('<ul><li>' + divh + '</li></ul>');
    $('#prCol1').height(divh);
}
```

Comment: Have a quick look at my jsfiddle, sir ;-)