# Two divs inside another div 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div container (`multiple_prizes` in the fiddle), that contains other two divs: one that has an upload button (`upload_prize_img`) and the other one has 3 inputs (`upload_prize_form`). The two inside `divs` are one beside each other with bootstrap columns. As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/SrL49/

(btw I could make `bootstrap` to work in JSFiddle , if anyone knows how, please tell me. That's the reason I simulated the same effect floating the inside divs)

As you can see, the `form` div is bigger than the `upload` div, and the `upload` div has a border. I want that div to have the same height as the form, so the border wraps from `name` to `amount`.

I tried almost any combination of `height: 100%` in all 3 divs, anyone has a solution for this? If you can use the bootstrap grid it would be better, but if you use floating divs it's ok too.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrL49/1/) Do you need this??

Comment: So I have to put a specific height to the divs? I don't know the height of the `upload div`, I just want the first one to get the same height

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to do this job.

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/SrL49/5/)

```
var divh = document.getElementById('upload_prize_form').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('upload_prize_img').style.height = divh + 'px';
```

Btw. I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004498/get-height-of-a-div-and-set-the-height-of-another-div-using-it).

Answer (score 1):

You can style it as a table: http://jsfiddle.net/SrL49/6/

```
.row {
   display: table;
}

#upload_prize_img
{
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 33%;
   display: table-cell;
}

#upload_prize_form
{
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 66%;
   display: table-cell;
}
```